# Change lockscreen clock color windows 11

Tags: windows-11, lock-screen

I was trying to change windows 11 lockscreen clock color, I searched and was hoping could find some registry edit to do so, but could not find anything :(
any idea?

Comment: See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/lock-screen-clock-colors/f4171144-fa48-404f-a401-7202cdfdec3d or use a different lock background pic?